# Converting XML to JSON on the server, is it the best choice on this context? or stick to XML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, json

I am relatively new to programming and need some help. Currently my web app gets some data from an XML file when calling `app.init()` and creates a custom object `box` for each node `<box>` with its child elements `<var1>, <var2>, ...` as its properties. The XML file looks like this:

```
<content>
    <box>
        <var1>A1</var1>
        <var2>B1</var2>
        <var3>C1</var3>
        <var4>D1</var4>
    </box>
    <box>
        <var1>A2</var1>
        <var2>B2</var2>
        <var3>C2</var3>
        <var4>D2</var4>
    </box>
    <box>
        <var1>A3</var1>
        <var2>B3</var2>
        <var3>C3</var3>
        <var4>D3</var4>
    </box>
</content>
```

and my app.init() method:

```
var app = {
    //...
    box: [],

    init: function (file) {
        var that = this;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: file,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                $("box", xml).each(function (i) {
                    var e = $(this);
                    that.box[i] = new Box(i, {
                        var1: e.children("var1").text(),
                        var2: e.children("var2").text(),
                        var3: e.children("var3").text(),
                        var4: e.children("var4").text()
                    });
                });
            },
        });
    },
    //...
};
```

I use XML because it is what I know and because I manipulate the data in EXCEL which allows me to easily export it in XML format. I am considering using JSON because as far as I've read it is considered a better format for AJAX, and because I use the data to create objects I think JSON may be a smarter choice, however I still need to use EXCEL and because I change the data constantly I would like to avoid the extra step of converting the XML file to JSON on each modification. I've thought maybe a solution would be to create an intermediate PHP file to convert the XML to JSON on the server, that way I upload the XML and my App reads the JSON generated by the PHP. I am not familiar with JSON and don't know if this would be a best practice.

Is JSON really THAT better to be worth doing the extra step (XML->PHP->JSON)? What are the implications on server usage? should I just stick to XML?

**Note:** The XML file has around 500 box elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the conversion part, take a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/

Comment: I think you should change your focus, and work on converting a csv file (which you can export to from excel) to JSON.  I could write a program to do that in PHP or python in a few lines if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your app appears to be written in Javascript, you should probably use JSON (which means "JavaScript Object Notation", after all) for feeding it data, particularly if performance is an issue.  That said, if you've already done the work to parse XML in Javascript, and it works, *and* you're not going to be making schema changes at any point, then [If It Ain't Broke Don't Fix It](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IfItAintBrokeDontFixIt) might apply.